# What's the "start" symbol of an executable built with libc++ on OS X

Tags: macos, linker, xcode7, libc++

I have a C++ project in XCode 7 that I just changed to use libc++ instead of libstdc++.

Now when I nm the executable that is generated, it does no longer have a `T start` symbol. What is the symbol that is called now to start the executable, now that I use the new libc++?

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of `_main`?

```
 0000000100000e20 T _main
```

This symbol appears whether I build with clang/libc++ or gcc/libstdc++

Comment: The solution is in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14422570/794740 it's not related to libc++ itself, but to the fact that I set the deployment target to >10.8, which causes different startup code to be generated. The difference is explained in the linked answer.