# gdb layout asm : Function "main" not defined

Tags: assembly, gdb, reverse-engineering

The problem related to question [Reversed Mach-O 64-bit x86 Assembly analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44086488/reversed-mach-o-64-bit-x86-assembly-analysis)

You might want to read it first.

I am currently switch to gdb debugging mode to track data flow. However, I have figured out. There is no "main" function defined.

GDB is also confused when I fired "layout asm":
[image]

Why this happened, and what I can do for it?

Answer (score 1):

> GDB is also confused when I fired "layout asm"

No, gdb was confused when you fired `start`, this has nothing to do with `layout asm`

> Why this happened

Because `start` sets temporary breakpoint on `main` function and runs program.
As you say your binary has no `main` function you can't expect that gdb will set breakpoint on `main`. Moreover `./Hello` has no debugging symbols as you can see from gdb output.

> what I can do for it?

This depends on what is your goal. If you want to analyze assembly you can do it with objdump as your did it in [Reversed Mach-O 64-bit x86 Assembly analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44086488/72178).