# GDB print string in an wrong format, a little like octal string

Tags: assembly, encryption, gdb, decoding

I show charset in my gdb:

```
The host character set is "UTF-8".
The target character set is "UTF-8".
The target wide character set is "auto; currently UTF-32".
```

But when I try to output a string in a register

> p (char*) $register

I got a very strange string which hard to recognise:

> $16 = 0x100001040 "A\020\021\021\033\ndgjhbhnghkb=ejj=h\004\005\b\003 ...

I am sure that if the string is purely ascii, all works fine.

So what should I do to get the string I want to see?

Comment: It seems that whatever is at the address contained in `register`, it is not a string.

Comment: I finally got the answer this might be a corrupted result. Your adjudgment is right that it is not a string but corrupted binary. I modified the codes and got the result I want. Thank you !